# Group by arraylist of objects without creating map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have object PayBill, that contains list of items. Object Item contains article. This article is connected to another Nomenclature object, which is stored as db table with next structure:

```
Article ProductGroup
------- ------------
010101  Telephone
040444  Computer
```

I parsed my transaction list into object Stat with next attributes: `payBillNumber`, `productGroup`, `amountOfItems`, `sumPriceOfItems`. Now list of `Stat` looks like:

```
BillNumber ProductGroup NumberOfItemsInBill SummaryItemsCostInBill
---------- ------------ ------------------- ----------------------
1          Telephone    1                   1000
1          Computer     1                   200
1          Telephone    2                   2000
1          Computer     1                   200
2          Accessories  1                   1500
```

How can I collapse this `List<Stat>` into new `List<Stat>` with following view:

```
BillNumber ProductGroup NumberOfItemsInBill SummaryItemsCostInBill
---------- ------------ ------------------- ----------------------
    1          Telephone    3                   3000
    1          Computer     2                   400
    2          Accessories  1                   1500
```

I want my data to be grouped by BillNumber and ProductGroup with amount an price summing. Is it possible to do without creating new Map?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector) baeldung blog. There is the groupby Collector descriped. Maybe it helps you with your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come up with a solution involving intermediate maps, but in a functional way using `groupingBy` and `reducing`:

```
List<Stat> collect = stats.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Stat::getBillNumber, Collectors.groupingBy(Stat::getProductGroup,
            Collectors.reducing((left, right) -> new Stat(
                    left.getBillNumber(), 
                    left.getProductGroup(), 
                    left.getNumberOfItemsInBill() + right.getNumberOfItemsInBill(),
                    left.getSummaryItemsCostInBill() + right.getSummaryItemsCostInBill()
            )))))
    .values().stream()
    .flatMap(m -> m.values().stream())
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that this results in a lot of `Stat` objects being created. If performance is an issue, you can come up with some aggregator and use `Collectors.of` instead of `Collectors.reducing` or stick to `reducing` and map it at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create the `Stat` constructor, but it goes like this:

```
Collection<Stat> aggregated = stats.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(
    stat -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(stat.getProductGroup(), stat.getBillNumber()),
    stat -> stat,
    (stat1, stat2) -> new Stat(stat1.getBillNumber(), stat1.getProductGroup(), stat1.getNumberOfItemsInBill() + stat2.getNumberOfItemsInBill(), stat1.getSummaryItemsCostInBill() + stat2.getSummaryItemsCostInBill()
  ))
  .values();
```

Comment: this doesn't group the items, as they need to be grouped by BillNumber and ProductGroup

Comment: I corrected the answer since I didn't notice the group by BillNumber. For 2 fields you can use `SimpleEntry`. With more grouping fields, you'll need to create a StatGrouping class, with grouping fields, and have equals/hashcode implemented properly.

Comment: @VinhTruong thanks, also worked) Didn't use `SimpleEntry` too much, so just forgot about such option. Looks like very clean solution

Answer (score 1):

I created the below class to represent data in sort form.

```
@Data
class Stat{
    int bn;
    String pg;
    int noOfBills;
    int cost;
    public Stat(int bn, String pg, int noOfBills, int cost)
    {
        this.bn = bn;
        this.pg = pg;
        this.noOfBills = noOfBills;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.bn + " - " + this.pg + " - " + this.noOfBills + " - " + this.cost;
    }
}
```

And here the main method with sample data i tested, you can collect instead of printing.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Stat> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Stat(1, "Telephone",1, 1000));
        list.add(new Stat(1, "Computer",1, 200));
        list.add(new Stat(1, "Telephone",2, 2000));
        list.add(new Stat(1, "Computer",1, 200));
        list.add(new Stat(2, "Accessories",1, 1500));
        
        list.stream().collect(toMap(Stat::getPg, Function.identity(),
                        (a, b) -> new Stat(a.getBn(), a.getPg(), a.getNoOfBills() + b.getNoOfBills(), a.getCost() + b.getCost())))
                .forEach((id,foo)->System.out.println(foo));
}
```

- Here I am using [two argument groupingBy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)